# Does Deathtouch apply to damage dealt via Fall of the Hammer?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does Deathtouch (from my creature) apply if [Fall of the Hammer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fall%20of%20the%20Hammer) is used on an enemy creature?

The rules say about deathtouch:

> The rule that causes creatures dealt damage by a source with deathtouch to be destroyed applies to any damage, not just combat damage.

Comment: That rule quote seems to make it pretty clear. What about this situation confuses you after reading that rule?

Comment: I wasn't sure if the creature is still the source, or if the spell `Fall of the Hammer` is the source. I thought it would apply, but wanted confirmation.

Comment: The question title is misleading. It appears to be about the Deathtouch mechanic, but when you read the body of the question, it's about how to identify the source of damage. This will make it difficult to identify duplicate questions in the future, and will also make it difficult for search engines to find your question and help others who have the same question but with a different card. I'd suggest something like *"Is Fall of the Hammer the source of damage?"* or *"What is the source of damage for Fall of the Hammer?"*

Comment: @Rainbolt however, would somebody who is not expert in magic use the terms "source of damage" in a search? It's more likely that they would search using the word deathtouch, or if deathtouch is not involved in their particular case, use some other term that is written on the card.

Comment: If you search for "fall of the hammer source of damage" in google, the second result (the first is this question, even without the words "source of damage" in the title) answers that. So yes, it seems the OP didn't search using those terms. And of course you could close the other question as a duplicate. That's something completely unrelated to editing the title or not.

Comment: @Rainbolt and if you search using google with "fall of the hammer deathtouch", you'll find even more results, because that's something that people actually ask and search more than "fall of the hammer source of damage".

Comment: @Pablo they probably would actually, once they got to the point that SpazzMarticus was in when asking this question. They had reached the rules quote using the words "dealt damage by a source with deathtouch" logically does lead to the question being "which object in this case is the source of the damage?"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Deathtouch does in fact apply when Fall of the Hammer is used. Fall specifically says that the first target creature deals the damage, and that means that this is treated just like any other instance of a creature dealing damage to another. Deathtouch applies; Lifelink applies; everything that applies to a creature dealing non-combat damage applies to this.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, if the creature you control has deathtouch, it will apply to Fall of the Hammer**

The rule on deathtouch is [702.2 in the comprehensive rules](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Deathtouch). The one that matters for this question is rule 702.2b:

> **702.2b** A creature with toughness greater than 0 that’s been dealt damage by a source with deathtouch since the last time state-based actions were checked is destroyed as a state-based action. See rule 704.

And the [referenced rule from 704](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/State-based_action) is pretty much a restating of this same rule:

> **704.5h** If a creature has toughness greater than 0, and it’s been dealt damage by a source with deathtouch since the last time state-based actions were checked, that creature is destroyed. Regeneration can replace this event.

These rule mean if the source of damage has deathtouch, then any damage is enough to destroy the creature. So the real question here is what the source of damage is, and the source of damage is explained at the beginning of Fall of the Hammer"

> "**Target creature you control deals damage** equal to its power to another target creature."

Fall of the hammer specifies that the damage is being dealt by "Target creature you control", since the creature is the source of the damage, abilities like Deathtouch and Lifelink will apply.

---

Note: As an example of a similar card where the creature abilities wouldn't apply, take a look at [Dragon's Breath](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dragon%27s%20Breath). The card lets you choose or reveal a dragon as you cast it, and uses that dragon's power to set the amount of damage, but it still specifies that the spell, not the creature, is the source of the damage:

> As an additional cost to cast this spell, you may reveal a Dragon card from your hand or choose a Dragon you control.
>
> Dragon's Fire deals 3 damage to target creature or planeswalker. If you revealed a Dragon card or chose a Dragon as you cast this spell, **Dragon's Fire deals damage** equal to the power of that card or creature instead.

---